# Java: Format a string as a telephone number

Tags: java

I have an unformatted telephone number string ("5551234567"). I would like to format this string for display purposes in the ui. The number should look like this after format:

(555) 123-4567

Sigh.....

I was trying to find a generic way that would take into account both US and international phone numbers. I came accross the MaskFormatter in the JDK but discovered that there is a bug in the Javadoc. Which lead me to asking my question here. I was hoping for a solution where I could input a mask then the actual string. The output would be formatted accordingly for international/US numbers or if the wrong number of characters were specified, some default character would be displayed in place of the missing characters........

http://www.java.net/node/660119

Comment: And how about our non US friends?

Comment: @JohnConnor Now I must know. What's the bug in http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/text/MaskFormatter.html?

Comment: @dlamblin If you would actually try the code you'll see the problem.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
String.format("(%s) %s-%s", number.substring(0, 3), number.substring(3, 6), 
          number.substring(6, 10));
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this homework? I'll leave it as an exercise to John to covert from Perl to Java. Should be simple; especially with something like http://www.regexbuddy.com/.

```
:~$ perl -pe 's/\D//g;s/^(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{0,4})(\d*)/(\1) \2-\3/'
5551234567
(555) 123-4567
```