# java format strings based on a pattern

Tags: java, regex, formatting

I have a requirement like this. My code generates random strings and it can be alpha, numeric and alphanumeric ones.

Lets say one of the numeric strings are "7882347812". I want to format this to 788.234.7812 based on a pattern like 3chars.3chars.4chars

If its an alphanumeric one like "h34jh8we7k". Then format this to h3/4jh8/we7k based on a pattern like 2chars/4chars/4chars.

If its an alpha one like "jkythjyv". Then format this to jky$thj$yv based on a pattern like 3chars$3chars$2chars.

In general, the generated strings can contain chars [a-zA-Z0-9]. This should be formatted as I mentioned above with any of the special characters. The input should be the string & the formatter and output should be the formatted string. Even a custom formatter is also fine.

I know how to write code for this. Is there any standard way of doing this in Java?

Comment: I assume you're trying to format phone numbers. There are several answers to this question already. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7730006/java-format-a-string-as-a-telephone-number), [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/487906/java-phone-number-format-api), and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8196771/format-a-string-using-regex-in-java)

Comment: No I am not. It can be any strings.

Comment: I got a solution for this and updated the answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I got a solution for this:

```
MaskFormatter formatter = new MaskFormatter("A-AAAA-AAAA-A");
formatter.setValueContainsLiteralCharacters(false);
System.out.println(formatter.valueToString("1222233334"));
```

The output would be 1-2222-3333-4

Check http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/MaskFormatter.html for more details

Comment: That is yet another creative solution! Good job.

Comment: Not applicable for Android

Answer (score 7):

You could do this through replaceAll function.

```
System.out.println("7882347812".replaceAll("^(\\d{3})(\\d{3})(\\d{4})$", "$1.$2.$3"));
```

Output:

```
788.234.7812
```

**OR**

```
System.out.println("foo bar 7882347812".replaceAll("\\b(\\d{3})(\\d{3})(\\d{4})\\b", "$1.$2.$3"));
```

Output:

```
foo bar 788.234.7812
```

Comment: This implies the whole string is a 10-digit string, while in his post he said "My code generates random strings and it can be alpha, numeric and alphanumeric ones", which means it _could_ result in strings +/-10 characters, with more than just numbers. Your example could probably update to account for that and answer the question more completely (though I do note the ambiguity of the request, so there's that...)

Comment: then it would be `\\b(\\d{3})(\\d{3})(\\d{4})\\b`

Answer (score 0):

```
^(.{3})(.{3})(.{4})$
```

Try this.This will work.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/xP1dE9/1

Comment: Whoa! regex101 is neat! As a side note, that might not work for the OP because it also accepts alpha characters.

Comment: @CoryKlein OP says random string generated can be alpha numeric etc.

Comment: Yea, it's ambiguous. His example gave a strictly numeric string, so I was assuming he only wanted to apply the pattern to numeric strings. (*shrug*) Whatever.

Comment: @Ani My answer still holds. No, there is not a standard way of doing this in Java. There are ways that work and ways that don't. There are elegant ways, and ugly ways.